# qsort c++:no matching function for call to 'qsort'

Tags: c++, sorting, qsort

This one is the compareX and compareY

```
struct Point
{
long long int x, y;
};


long long int compareX(const void* a, const void* b)
{
Point *p1 = (Point *)a,  *p2 = (Point *)b;
return (* (long long int * )(p1->x - p2->x));
}

long long int compareY(const void* a, const void* b)
{
Point *p1 = (Point *)a,   *p2 = (Point *)b;
return (* (long long int * )(p1->y - p2->y));
}
```

This is the qsort to call the compareY

```
long long int stripClosest(Point strip[], long long int size, long long int 
d)
{
long long int min = d; 

qsort(strip, size, sizeof(Point), compareY); 


for (long long int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    for (long long int j = i+1; j < size && (strip[j].y - strip[i].y) < min; 
++j)
        if (dist(strip[i],strip[j]) < min)
            min = dist(strip[i], strip[j]);

return min;
}
```

This is the qsort to call the compareX

```
long long int closest(Point P[], long long int n)
{
qsort(P, n, sizeof(Point), compareX);

return closestUtil(P, n);
}
```

and I don't know why it is said "note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'long long (const void *, const void *)' to 'int (* _Nonnull)(const void *, const void *)' for 4th argument" and "error: no matching function for call to 'qsort'"

Comment: If I use int instead of long long int, it works totally fine, I don't know why is the problem by using long long int.

Comment: Why do you cast the result, x-y to be a pointer?

Comment: Don't you think that the problem might be that `int`and `long long int` are *different types*?

Comment: I'd recommend using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead of `qsort()`.

Comment: And `(* (long long int * )(p1->x - p2->x))` is nonsense. Move beyond the 1970s and use `std::sort`.

Comment: You appear very confused about pointers here. I echo the previous comment, `(* (long long int * )(p1->x -> p2->x));` is nonsense (even in a C program). And also, this code is not in any way C++ code, this is C code.

Comment: Stop using `qsort` in a C++ program.  There's so much casting, it looks like a Hollywood movie.  `std::sort(strip, strip + size, [&](auto& p1, auto& p2) { return p1.x > p1.y;});` Now doesn't that look a lot simpler?

Comment: Okay bro thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The function qsort requires that the function type of the corresponding parameter would be

```
int ( const void *, const void * )
```

also this magic with pointers

```
* (long long int * )(p1->x - p2->x)
```

is unclear and results in undefined behavior.

Thus for example the function `compareX` can be defined the following way

```
int compareX(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const Point *p1 = static_cast<const Point *>(a);
    const Point *p2 = static_cast<const Point *>(b);

    return (p2->x < p1->x) - (p1->x < p2->x);
}
```

Or it can be declared with the "C" linkage

```
extern "C" int compareX(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const Point *p1 = static_cast<const Point *>(a);
    const Point *p2 = static_cast<const Point *>(b);

    return (p2->x < p1->x) - (p1->x < p2->x);
}
```

Take into account that in C++ you can use standard algorithm `std::sort` with a comparison function.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the both approaches with using the standard C function `qsort` and the standard C++ algorithm `std::sort`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Point
{
    long long int x;
    long long int y;
};

int compareX(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const Point *p1 = static_cast<const Point *>(a);
    const Point *p2 = static_cast<const Point *>(b);

    return (p2->x < p1->x) - (p1->x < p2->x);
}

int main()
{
    {
        Point p[] = { { 2, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 3, 1 } };

        qsort(p, sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p), sizeof(Point), compareX);

        for (const auto &item : p)
        {
            std::cout << "(" << item.x << ", " << item.y << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    {
        Point p[] = { { 2, 1 },{ 1, 1 },{ 3, 1 } };

        std::sort( std::begin( p ), std::end( p ),
            [](const Point &a, const Point &b)
            {
                return a.x < b.x;
        });

        for (const auto &item : p)
        {
            std::cout << "(" << item.x << ", " << item.y << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
(1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1)
(1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1)
```

Comment: hey thanks bro I got it. Your explanation is very clear.